# Error "URL.hostname is not implemented", AWS SNS in React Native Android

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk-js

Using SNS service from the AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 in React Native

When I try to create an endpoint (or execute really any command through AWS) I'm getting this error `URL.hostname is not implemented`

- I tried a number of other commands; same error
- The only thing I've done that yields a different error is if I remove `region` from the params when creating the client. Then it errors `Region is missing` in the same place. But worth noting, if I just pass nonsense (`asdf123`) for region it yields this same URL.hostname error

```
import { CognitoIdentityClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity";
import { SNSClient, CreatePlatformEndpointCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";

const region = 'us-west-2'
const sns = new SNSClient({
    region: region,
    credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
        client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region }),
        identityPoolId: identityPoolId,
    }) /// doesn't matter whether I pass credentials or not, same result
});

const params = {
    PlatformApplicationArn: platformApplicationArn,
    Token: token
}

const command = new CreatePlatformEndpointCommand(params);  

const res = await sns.send(command)
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err) //// this is the "[Error: not implemented]"
    throw err 
})
```

This is saying I should have more data in this error but the only thing in this error is the message. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sns/index.html#troubleshooting

Seems like this isn't even an AWS error...but I have no idea how to troubleshoot further.

Any suggestions on how to identify where this is coming from would be SUPER APPRECIATED. Thanks all

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found some posts which suggested this for similar errors: `react-native-url-polyfill`

Once that was added I started getting this error instead:
`[Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]`

To solve this I added `react-native-get-random-values`

... and it works. I'm not sure I understand why, or what the root cause is, and this seems like kinda a messy workaround. But it does work.

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
//at the top of the file where I'm handling AWS SNS
```

If anyone out there can shed light on what's going on here, no doubt there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked for me too as I was trying to get files from an S3 bucket.  I'm guessing, for me, it was something to do with the AWS GetObjectCommand needing a particular format of URL as the key, which in turn requires some hashing, hence the need for random numbers.  I couldn't tell you exactly why, but this saved me.  +1000

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Had the same issue. Found out that these two packages are required if using AWS's modular interfaces. This is documented here in their Getting Started guide https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3#getting-started

Comment: you're amazing. how did you even figure this out? saved my life

Comment: Thanks enesefuu and @DanielLong for your help on this. I also found the link to amplify react-native documentation https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react-native/getting-started/installation which states the same to import these two packages