# URL.hostname is not implemented

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk-js, amazon-textract

I'm looking for some help on my textract client project. I am trying to follow the AWS Textract documentation, but I am stuck at the textractClient.send(). I am getting the error **URL.hostname is not implemented**

I have followed the steps on AWS to set up my IAM, S3, and I have updated my ~/.aws/config and credentials files. I left out a couple of fields but here's my code:

```js
import { AnalyzeExpenseCommand } from  "@aws-sdk/client-textract";
import  { TextractClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-textract";
...
const textractClient = new TextractClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const bucket = 'scannsplit-s3-bucket'
const photo = 'Sojuba.png'

// Set params
const params = {
    Document: {
        S3Object: {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Name: photo
        },
    },
}
...
const process_text_detection = async () => {
    try {
        const aExpense = new StartExpenseAnalysisCommand(params);
        console.log(aExpense);
        const response = await textractClient.send(aExpense);
        console.log(response);
        return response; // For unit tests.
     } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }
}
...
process_text_detection() is being called with a button
```

What I've tried:
I came across this other post [Error "URL.hostname is not implemented", AWS SNS in React Native Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413410/error-url-hostname-is-not-implemented-aws-sns-in-react-native-android) that seems to have a similar issue. I tried the solution and after I installed **react-native-url-polyfill** and **react-native-get-random-values**, I got the error **Native module is not found**. I tried looking for fixes for that error but also did not have much luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This worked for me - see the top response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413410/error-url-hostname-is-not-implemented-aws-sns-in-react-native-android